# How do I suppress certain fields in NLOG structured logging?

Tags: c#, nlog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!--This NLog config is for testing purposes only. Changes to this config will affect test cases and not the real application.-->
    <!--Changes to the config in production ARE NOT reflected here-->
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          internalLogLevel="Warn"
          internalLogFile="/tmp/nlog-internal.log">
        <variable name="baseLayout" value="${longdate} ${level:upperCase=true} ${message}" />
        <!--async attribute set to "false" for log testing purposes. Changing this will break log tests 4/4/2021-->
        <targets async="false">
            <target name="NoPiiLog" xsi:type="Memory">
                <layout type="JsonLayout">
                    <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                    <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
                    <!-- <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" /> -->
                    <attribute name="event" encode="false" >
                        <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="2"
                         excludeProperties="UserId,EmailId" excludeEmptyProperties="true"/>
                    </attribute>
                </layout>
            </target>
            <target name="WithPiiLog" xsi:type="Memory" layout="${structuredlogging.json}">
                <layout type="JsonLayout">
                    <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                    <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
                    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
                    <attribute name="event" encode="false" >
                        <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="2"/>
                    </attribute>
                </layout>
            </target>
        </targets>
        <rules>
            <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="NoPiiLog,WithPiiLog" />
        </rules>
    </nlog>
</configuration>
```

And the logging code:

```
            var obj = new
            {
                EmailId = "mark@gmail.com",
                OtherValue = "You should see this"
            };

    var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Test");

    logger.Info("Problems Processing @{event}", obj);

    logger.Info(ex, "Houston, we have a problem @{event}", new {UserId="mark@gmail.com", SomethingElse= "oh no! Mr Bill!"});

    logger.Error("@{event}", new{Message="Poorly Named property", SlipsThru="mark@gmail.com"});
```

And the log messages:

```
{ "time": "2021-08-04 13:37:59.2163", "level": "Info", "event": { "event": {"EmailId":"mark@gmail.com", "OtherValue":"You should see this"} } }
{ "time": "2021-08-04 13:37:59.2585", "level": "Info", "event": { "event": {"UserId":"mark@gmail.com", "SomethingElse":"oh no! Mr Bill!"} } }
{ "time": "2021-08-04 13:37:59.2600", "level": "Error", "event": { "event": {"Message":"Poorly Named property", "SlipsThru":"mark@gmail.com"} } }
```

The only email that should be in the logs is the one on the SlipsThru property, but all of them are appearing in the log and I don't understand why.  How should this be configured to hide the EmailId and UserId properties for this `target`?

I've also tried adding `includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="2" excludeProperties="UserId,EmailId" excludeEmptyProperties="true"` to the top level JsonLayout, again with no effect.....

Also, what's going on with the nesting of "event"

```
"event": { "event": {"EmailId":"mark@gmail.com", "OtherValue":"You should see this"} } }
```

I don't see any reason why this should get the nested expression

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend that you read this wiki-page about [How to use structured logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging)

> How should this be configured to hide the EmailId and UserId properties for this target?

`logger.Info("Problems Processing {event}", obj);` means create LogEvent with property-key `event` with property-value `obj`. `excludeProperties` can only be used for property-keys not for diving into property-values and handpicking specific class-properties.

You can manually slice the `obj`-value into property-keys like this:

```
logger.Info("Problems Processing {EmailId} {OtherValue}", obj.EmailId, obj.OtherValue);
```

Alternative if you have a "known" object-type, then you can [register transformation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#customize-object-reflection) of the object-type to a safe-object with only the wanted properties:

```
LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
   s.RegisterObjectTransformation<MyUnsafeObject>(obj => new {
      OtherValue = obj.OtherValue
   })
);
```

Yet another alternative is to [override the builtin NLog-Json-Converter](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#how-to-override-json-formatter) and supply one that can render the objects as you want.

> Also, what's going on with the nesting of "event"

You have specified `<attribute name="event" encode="false">`, so it will create an `event`-json-attribute, that will render all [NLog LogEvent Properties](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) (`includeAllProperties="true"`). And the message-template `logger.Info("Problems Processing {event}", obj);` will capture property-key `event` with value `obj` (Thus `event`-attribute has a nested `event`-property)