# Excluding one Entry property in DBUpdateException from log in NLog

Tags: entity-framework-core, nlog

I have an entity with `byte[]` property, when `DBUpdateException` occurs it pours it into a json log, since `DbUpdateException` contains `Entries` list, which includes every single entry's\entity property. I wonder if there is a way to prevent this one property to be logged. I'm using `NLog 5.2.5` (JsonLayout), `EF Core 5`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I suppress certain fields in NLOG structured logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68657118/how-do-i-suppress-certain-fields-in-nlog-structured-logging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the property-relection for an object-type like this:

```cs
LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
   s.RegisterObjectTransformation<DBUpdateException>(ex => new {
      Type = ex.GetType().ToString(),
      Message = ex.Message,
      StackTrace = ex.StackTrace,
      Source = ex.Source,
      Data = ex.Data,
      InnerException = ex.InnerException,
   })
);
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#customize-object-reflection